# Red Hat Kickstart install stops to ask me to edit the repository when I'm using the DVD repo

Tags: kickstart, rhel6

So, I've been trying to get a kickstart install with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2 to work, using the package repo on the DVD. As such, I've tried using the following line in my `ks.cfg`:

```
 repo --name="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"  --baseurl=cdrom:sr0 --cost=100
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. The installer can't find the repo, and the install fails. Have I got the `repo` syntax wrong?

UPDATE: It looks like I've got a more serious problem. Even if I boot without using the kickstart file, the installer reports that there is a problem with the generation of my install tree. I'm going to go ahead and run this install manually now, but it is a bummer that I can't get kickstart to work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're still working on this, because I ran into something similar when I was building my own iso. You need to set the baseurl to file://mnt/source to load from the repository on the DVD, e.g.

```
repo --name="Scientific Linux" --baseurl=file:///mnt/source --cost=100
```

When kickstart is able to find the repo, it will also resolve your install tree error. At least, it did for me.

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

The path was changed, consider trying the following:

```
repo --name="Scientific Linux" --baseurl=file:///mnt/install/source --cost=100
```